# Get the post ID only off single page

Tags: plugin-development

I will begin by saying that I am skilled PHP developper but brand new to WP.

My idea is to make a plugin that increments a value every time a post is seen (I mean the complete "page" that contains the post). For a while, I succeed to have an increment every time a post is loaded (wether for navigation purpose, partial display...). My other requirement is that it is not theme dependant. I have found many solutions that are.
I cannot succeed to retrieve the post ID of the main post in the page. So far, what I did looks like that :

```
function setPostView( $post_object ) {
    $post = get_query_var('post_id'); //that does not work but I need something similar
    if ($post_object->ID==$post){
        $postID = $post_object->ID;
        $count_key = 'post_views_count';
        $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
        if($count==''){
            $count = 0;
            delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
            add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        }else{
            $count++;
            update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'the_post', 'setPostView' );
```

Comment: `get_query_var('post_id')` will return the page id on which you are.
What query do you have on page to display the posts use the same query to get post ids here! 

I am sorry if I didn't get you well.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand, but maybe the [function is_main_query() will work](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query)

Comment: this function seems to be what I need but I do not get how to retrieve "the query" in the action "the_post" as I need the post to update metaoption. can you help me more ?